# Capture Blackmagic and other external video capture cards in Flash Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, camera

The ustream Flash web app allows you to select Video source including attached capture cards. Looking at the Camera class I can't see any option to list capture cards in Flash. Is there another class or library that returns a list of video capture devices on the system?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Looking at the Camera class I can't see any option to list capture cards`

This is what you wanted?: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#names

```
//get Array listing of Cameras (aka capture devices)    
for (var i:int = 0; i < Camera.names.length; i++)
{
    trace("Available Device : " + Camera.names[i]); //String of each device name
}
```

`Camera.names.length` let's you know how many you have (counting from zero for first one, if any available or else it'll give you a null).

To put specific camera name to String then use:
`var str_CamName_A : String = Camera.names[0];`
`var str_CamName_B : String = Camera.names[1];`

To show names in some textbox or textfield then use:
`myCameraList.text = str_CamName_A`